# How do you access aqObject methods in TestComplete through COM?

Tags: com, testcomplete

Specifically I am trying to do the equivalent of

```
aqObject.IsSupported(objText, "SomeProperty")
```

through the TestComplete COM interface.

How do you do this?

**Note:**

I am connecting to TestComplete through WIN32OLE by connecting to `"TestComplete.TestCompleteApplication.8"`.

It is probably worth point out that I have attempted to ask the integration to get the aqObject by name and got NULL back.

sys = tc.integration.GetObjectByName("Sys")
sys.Exists 
=> true
sys.Name 
=> "Sys"

aqObject = tc.integration.GetObjectByName("aqObject") 
=> nil

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Actually I am trying this in both ruby using Win32Ole and VBScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a running test in TestComplete at the moment? [This article](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/33145/#AutomatingTCWithIntegrationObject) says it's a prerequisite for `GetObjectByName`:

> You can obtain the object only if TestComplete is running a test. If there is no tests running in TestComplete, `GetObjectByName` will return an empty Variant value.

Comment: That's a shame. I am trying to avoid starting a test. I have a work around where I am just accessing the properties I want to check and catching the exceptions. It's not perfect but it works. :(

Comment: You may want to consider an approach Connected Apps are using - they can switch TestComplete to the test execution state without actually executing any test. In this state, GetObjectByName should work - check this help topic: http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/28579/#Routines

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Connected Applications](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/27178/) feature of TestComplete, you can easily access the **aqObject** object along with its members via the [Connect](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/38574/) class.

Comment: I am connecting to TestComplete through WIN32OLE by connecting to "TestComplete.TestCompleteApplication.8".  Connected applications seem to just use a dll that wraps the COM interface. Looking at script.h the `TestComplete::aqObject` is just a wrapper around `tc.integration.GetObjectByName("aqObject")` which isn't working.